# command not found - Python Django app deployment issue with DigitalOcean

Tags: python, django, deployment, digital-ocean

I’m having a problem with the package gunicorn on the app platform while it’s present in my requirements.txt file.

`bash: gunicorn: command not found`

With app platform, I am not able to find the flexibility to change the system configurations. Is there a way I can add the gunicorn binary to $PATH or add a symlink somehow? I tried to build the app again and changed my run configuration but it didn't help. The deployment fails after the build step. This error might make me to configure a bare metal server droplet which would be a bit tedious. Probably a noob question, but could someone help on this? I am blocked by this, so would really appreciate your help! Thank you in advance.